# ListView item with OnTouchListener results in multiple listening rows

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, ontouchlistener

I'm Building a list view with a custom adapter. I want each list item to respond on a ontouchlistener. So inside the getView() method assign the listener to the view before returning the view.

When I touch the row it needs to set the margin of the LinearLayout inside 200px form the left, and when I release the row it needs to set the margin back to 0.

I have chosen a OnTouchListener, because later in my project I want to handle some move events.

Here's my code:

```
public class BudgetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Budget>{

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private List<Budget> data = null;
    private View.OnTouchListener listener;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public BudgetAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Budget> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
        listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                LinearLayout front = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.budget_list_item_header);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                if ( motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    params.setMargins(0,0,200,0);
                    front.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
                if ( motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                {

                    params.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
                    front.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        this.inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        BudgetHolder holder;
        if(row == null)
        {
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new BudgetHolder();
            holder.titleText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.budget_list_item_title_label);
            holder.totalText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.budget_list_item_total_label);
            holder.remainingText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.budget_list_item_remaining_label);
            holder.remainingBar = (RemainingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.budget_list_item_remaining_bar);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (BudgetHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Budget budget = data.get(position);
        holder.titleText.setText(budget.getShortDescription());
        holder.totalText.setText("budget: " + budget.getTotal().toString());
        holder.remainingText.setText(budget.getRemainingAsString());
        holder.remainingBar.setRemaining(budget.getExpensesAmount());
        holder.remainingBar.setTotal(budget.getTotal());

        row.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        return row;
    }

    static class BudgetHolder {
        TextView titleText;
        TextView totalText;
        TextView remainingText;
        RemainingBar remainingBar;
    }
}
```

I have the following problem.
When I touch a row, randomly some rows get the new margin (and some get it doubled to 400px). When I release the row randomly some rows, which had the margin doubled, will get the margin back to 200px or 0px.

How can I achieve wat I want, that only the touched row will respond on the events.

Comment: I think you need to apply the margin to the view. onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent). Rather than making a new RelativeLayout just get the current one with getLayoutParams() change the margin and setLayoutParams again.