# Get ImageView from touched row in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I want to get the ImageVIew of the touched row in a RecyclerView.

The problem is that all rows have the same ImageView ID:

[image]

This is a example from YouTube
 When touching a row the icon is changing:

[image]

For example when I'm touching the first row I want to create a ImageView object and do something with this but just with the ImageView from the first row!

The picture is with TextView but thats not interessting for the logic.

**UPDATED CODE**

```js
public class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.MySettingHolder> {

    private List<Settings> settingList;
    private Context context;

    public class MySettingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public int type;
        public ImageView settingImage;
        public TextView settingTitle, settingSubtitle;

        public MySettingHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            settingImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);
            settingTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingTitle);
            settingSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingSubtitle);
        }
    }

    public SettingsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SettingsAdapter(List<Settings> settingList) {
        this.settingList = settingList;
    }

    @Override
    public MySettingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.settings_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MySettingHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        // Setting for one entry
        final Settings setting = settingList.get(position);
        //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        holder.settingImage.setImageResource(setting.getSettingImageUrl());
        // If the settingSubtitle is empty it should be not visible and just the settingTitle
        if (setting.getSettingSubtitle().equals("")) {
            //params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            //params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            //params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingSubtitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
        }

        // Get setting holder type
        holder.type = setting.getType();

        // OnTouchListener for holder/vector color change
        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Define setting holder
                MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());


                // ImageView for changing color
                ImageView settingImageRow = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);

                // Detect if user touch or not
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Change ImageView color to primary color
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(settingImageRow.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Change ImageView color to icon color
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(settingImageRow.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.iconGray));
                }


                return false;
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for holder
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Define setting holder
                MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());

                // Define switch for line
                switch (holder.type) {
                    // Case 1 = Logout
                    case 1:
                        // OnCLickListener for an event
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {

                                    // Case user types Yes
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                        // Deleting shared preferences for login activity
                                        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = v.getRootView().getContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginPreferences.edit();
                                        editor.clear();
                                        editor.commit();

                                        // Start new activity for login
                                        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class));

                                        // Exit activity
                                        ((Activity) v.getContext()).finish();

                                        // Exit case button positive/yes
                                        break;

                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                        // Dismiss dialog
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                        // Exit case button negative/no
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        // AlertDialog for logout check
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Möchtest du dich wirklich abmelden?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ja", dialogClickListener)
                                .setNegativeButton("Nein", dialogClickListener)
                                .show();

                        // Exit switch
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // do other stuff
                        break;

                    default:

                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setTag(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return settingList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the code that you currently have.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie I've already posted a question with code but nobody answered it because I think it was to complicated...

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie The problem is that I get all TextViews from the RecyclerView with my code and not just the touched one

Comment: What is happening with the actual code? Did you run it?

Comment: Yes I did. When I touch a row the color of all icons are changing but it should be just the one from the touched row :(

Comment: You should be able to look up the textview the same way you are looking up the imageview but... their are easier ways to accomplish an icon color change.

Comment: But it should be in an OnTOuchListener. Can you give me an answer how you would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parentView.findViewById(id)` looks for a child inside the `parentView`that has an specific ID.
So, you should be able to find the desired inner-row-view, by calling `findViewById` without any problem.

You're currently setting an `OnTouchListener` to the `RowView`.
If you get the view as:

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //V is your row view, the touched one.
    ImageView settingImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);
    //This imageview is the imageview inside the touched row**.

    //You can also do this:
    settingImage = holder.settingImage


    return true;
}
```

The problem isn't the `findViewById()` and the views with the same ID.

You could even get the "someView" directly, inside the `onTouchListener()`.

Comment: I don't have an rowView

Comment: The view of your row. I presume you're doing all of this inside the "onBindViewHolder" method.

Comment: So, who has the onTouchListener?

Comment: I've updated my code again with the whole adapter code :)

Comment: Oh, right. Forgot the name of the itemView field haha. Updated, another way of getting the imageView. Access the holder and it's imageView inside the onTouchListener.

Comment: Sorry mate but this code is the same as I programmed. And this don't working: settingImage = holder.settingImage

Comment: I've updated my question with a photo for you. And here is my problem again: When I'm touching a row **ALL** icons are changing the color and **NOT THE SINGLE ONE FROM THE TOUCHED LINE**

Comment: Com on guys that can't be so difficult

Comment: How did settingImage = holder.settingImage not work? Same result or compile error? Remember to declare holder as final: "public void onBindViewHolder(final MySettingHolder holder, ...)

Comment: I recomment logging the onTouchListener, just to be sure. Print the position of the touched view. Position at holder.position

Comment: No you don't understand! I'm getting the objects but all images are changing color!! All!!! It should be just the touched one!

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/q/26886027/7267238 this buddy have the same problem but with setting a margin and not a color. Do you understand my problem now?

Comment: I got it a while ago. Why don't you try to put some log in the listener, so you can be sure what's going on, who is getting the call

Comment: How can I log this? :O

Comment: Log.d("debug", "row touched =" + holder.position);

Comment: Something, anything. We know what is happening, but we don't know why or what to do. We must find the reason to get the answer.

Comment: Okay I'll try in 30 minutes when I'm at work and I'll post the solution here. I think I need to debug this right?

Comment: When touching the first row the result is 0 and the second is 1

Comment: I've got it... I've defined a variable in the super class with final and the same name but android studio don't detect this "error". After renaming the variable all works fine!

Comment: Hahahahaahhhha that's crazy. Nice!

Comment: There was another problem. Solution at the bottom. Would be very happy if you can mark it as good :)

Comment: I though that by removing the finger out of the view bounds the Touch.UP wouldn't be called, but the CANCEL would. Good to see it working!

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

The first problem was that there was a variable `settingImage` which was in an upper class and final so it was overwritten by the other variable. The second problem was the part where I set the color tint. There was something wrong th this code so I removed it and made a new solution:

```js
// OnTouchListener for holder/vector color change
        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Define setting holder
                MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());

                //Log.d("debug","row touched =" + holder.getLayoutPosition());
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Change ImageView color to primary color
                    holder.settingImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Change ImageView color to icon color
                    holder.settingImage.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.iconGray));
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just have one question for this. What's happens if you touch, drag your finger out is the row, then remove finger.

Comment: The color is still set until my finger is removed

Comment: Thanks for giving my brain a little "touch". I'll update my question.